# Symbol for the complex plane from Peskin and Schroeder?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Peskin and Schroeder's QFT text often uses the notation shown in the picture below to denote the complex plane of a variable. I don't think this notation is standard and I couldn't find a way to implement it when I googled around. How do I achieve this in Tikz?

Edit: To clarify the question I meant just the bit that looks like a right angle with $p^0$ in the picture below (does this have a name?). I included this code just to have a minimum working example, I didn't mean I wanted the exact same contour.

[image: Complex Plane]

I have the code below for the contour I desire:

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    decoration={%
      markings,
      mark=at position 2.35619cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
      mark=at position 4.71239cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
      mark=at position 7.06858cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
      mark=at position 10.9248cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
      mark=at position 13.9248cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
    }
  ]
  \draw [help lines,->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) coordinate (xaxis);
  \draw [help lines,->] (0,-4) -- (0,1) coordinate (yaxis);
  \node at (0,-2) {$\times$};
  \node at (0.6,-2) {$-ip^1$};
  \path [draw, line width=0.8pt, postaction=decorate] (3,0) node [above] {$R$} arc (0:-180:3) node [above] {$-R$} -- (3,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me if the following is a stupid question, but *what is your question?* Is there something missing from the figure your code produces and if so what is still missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to produce something that resembles Peskin's plot for the integration contour of the Feynman propagator.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [Peskin arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={%
      markings,
      mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{stealth}},}}}
  ]
  \draw [help lines] (-4,0) -- (4,0) coordinate (xaxis);
  \draw [help lines] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) coordinate (yaxis);
  \node (p0) at (6,1) {$p^0$};
  \draw (p0.north west) -- (p0.south west)  -- (p0.south east);
  \draw[line width=0.8pt, Peskin arrow=0.2, Peskin arrow=0.8] 
  (-3.5,-0.8) -- (3.5,0.8); 
  \fill (-2,0) circle(2pt) (2,0) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer to the updated question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{Peskin/.style={path picture={\draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.north
west) -- (path picture bounding box.south west)
-- (path picture bounding box.south east);}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[Peskin]{$p^0$};} \tikz{\node[Peskin=blue]{$p^0$};}
\tikz{\node[Peskin=thick]{$p^0$};} \tikz{\node[Peskin={blue,thick}]{$p^0$};}

\dots and here is how Michael may have done it: $\begin{array}{|c}p^0\\
\hline\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I didn't mean I wanted Peskin's exact contour, I just meant that bit at the top right where it has $p^0$ in a right-angle looking thing, I wasn't sure what to call it. That code was for the contour I'm actually trying to add that symbol to, which I did write myself. But thanks to your answer I've now figured out how to add  the arrows without stupidly calculating the loop circumference in cm, thanks.

Comment: @Ash I see. OK, I added more options, even one without Ti*k*Z, which may come close to what has been used by the authors themselves. (The book is much older than Ti*k*Z, and if you look at the homepage of the book and check how Wick contractions are done in the book, you probably start to appreciate the existence of Ti*k*Z and its descendants like `simpler-wick`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the arrow tips?

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [>=Latex,
    decoration={%
        markings,
        mark=at position 2.35619cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
        mark=at position 4.71239cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
        mark=at position 7.06858cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
        mark=at position 10.9248cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
        mark=at position 13.9248cm with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{>}},
    }
    ]
    \draw [help lines,->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) coordinate (xaxis);
    \draw [help lines,->] (0,-4) -- (0,1) coordinate (yaxis);
    \node at (0,-2) {$\times$};
    \node at (0.6,-2) {$-ip^1$};
    \path [draw, line width=0.8pt, postaction=decorate] (3,0) node [above] {$R$} arc (0:-180:3) node [above] {$-R$} -- (3,0); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice try but the cat is Schrödinger's ;)

Comment: Thank you, I've clarified my question to point out I just meant that symbol in the top right corner with $p^0$, but thanks for helping me figure out the arrow style :).

Comment: @Ash Your question was much simpler than I thought, then, lol